# Laravel : checking the time by whereBetween clause

Tags: mysql, laravel

i want to check if the time entered is existed already in the db or not? here in $dbsum and $dbesum i am doing the sum like if i enter starttime 11:30 then it will give 690 in $dbsum and if i enter endtime 12.30 then it will give 750 in $dbesum. 'c_start' and 'c_end' is the sum that already existed in the database.Now i want to check if $dbsum and $dbesum existed between 'c_start' and 'c_end' or not. my query is like below in controller. but it's not working.

```
    $dbstime = explode(':',$request->input('starttime'));
    $dbetime = explode(':',$request->input('endtime'));

    $dbstime[0] = $dbstime[0]*60;
    $dbetime[0] = $dbetime[0]*60;

    $dbsum = array_sum($dbstime);
    $dbesum = array_sum($dbetime); 

     $users=DB::table("bookings")
    ->select("bookdate")
    ->where([
            ['bookdate', '=', $request->input('bookdate')],
            ['roomname', '=', $request->input('roomname')],
            ['starttime', '=', $request->input('starttime')],
            ['endtime', '=', $request->input('endtime')],
    ->whereBetween('c_start', [$dbsum, $dbesum])
    ->whereBetween('c_end', [$dbsum, $dbesum])

    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $users=DB::table("bookings") 
    ->select("id") 
    ->where('bookdate', '=', $request->input('bookdate')) 
    ->where('roomname', '=', $request->input('roomname')) 
    ->where(function ($query){
    $query->where($dbsum, '>', 'c_start');
    $query->orWhere($dbsum, '<', 'c_end');
    })
    ->orWhere(function($query){
    $query->where($dbesum, '>', 'c_start');
    $query->orWhere($dbesum, '<', 'c_end');
    }) 
    ->get();
```

Comment: Are you sure, that you have row in your table with data of your inputs?

Comment: can u tell me how will i write this query..
  $users=DB::table("bookings")
                ->select("id")
                ->where('bookdate', '=', $request->input('bookdate'))
                ->where('roomname', '=', $request->input('roomname'))                         )
                ->where(($dbsum, '>', 'c_start'or $dbsum, '<', 'c_end') or ($dbesum, '>', 'c_start' or $dbesum, '<', 'c_end'))
                ->get();
it's showing unexpected ')' in this line-  ->where('roomname', '=', $request->input('roomname'))